# Binding visibility of usercontrol does not collapse control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

i do have a problem with binding the visibility of my usercontrol.

The binding to a Dependency Property of type Visibility works fine and the correct value (in this case Collapsed) is held by the DP. The content of my Grid within the UserControl is set to collapsed, but the hole control doesnt collapse. It still keeps the space occupied defined by with and heigth, as referenced in the xaml.

EDIT: i found out, that the problem is that i set width and height in the xaml where i reference my usercontrol. if i don't do this, the control collapses correct (therefore binding works fine). But i need to set width and heigth in case the usercontrol is visible.

Any idea how i can solve this problem?

```
<my:MenuButtonBase x:Class="bxSuite.Controls.MenuButtonLarge"
             xmlns:my="clr-namespace:bxSuite.Controls"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             Background="Black" 
             >
    <Grid Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ButtonVisibility}" >
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{Binding ButtonImageSource}" Margin="5,10,5,5" Width="48" Height="48" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding FunctionHeader}" Foreground="White" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="5,5,5,5" FontSize="12" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</my:MenuButtonBase>
```

In XAML i reference my usercontrol like this (where the Converter produces the visibility-state correctly):

```
<my:MenuButtonLarge Name="btnInEuqipment" ButtonVisibility="{Binding Path=User, Converter={StaticResource ConverterUserRightVisibility}, ConverterParameter=5}" VerticalAlignment="Top" FunctionHeader="{lex:Loc Key=MenuButton_InEquipment}" Width="130" ButtonImageSource="/bxSuite.RolloutManager;component/Images/inequipment_48x48.png" BackgroundEnabled="#FF0694FD" BackgroundHover="#FF0072C6" MenuButtonClick="btnInEuqipment_MenuButtonClick" Height="95" Margin="5,10,0,0" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try set the visibility of the user control instead of the grid, should work.

Your code should be like this.

```
<my:MenuButtonBase x:Class="bxSuite.Controls.MenuButtonLarge"
         xmlns:my="clr-namespace:bxSuite.Controls"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=ButtonVisibility}" 
         Background="Black">
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="{Binding ButtonImageSource}" 
               Margin="5,10,5,5" 
               Width="48" 
               Height="48" 
               VerticalAlignment="Top" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding FunctionHeader}" 
                   Foreground="White" 
                   TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                   TextAlignment="Center" 
                   Padding="5,5,5,5" 
                   FontSize="12" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Dont forget to update the RelativeSource of your bind.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanx for your suggestion. I put it the way you wrote, but as result the UControl is displayed like visible. But i think it might be because i dont get what you mean by "dont forget to update the relative source of your bind". I'll copy my xaml reference to the ticket above to show you how i use my usercontrol.